# Authenticate Local Windows User Accounts

Tags: active-directory, ldap, windows-authentication, directoryservices, adsi

I have written this JScript to validate Local Windows User Accounts:

```
function ValidateCredentials(strUsername, strPassword) {
  var ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = 1;
  var objWMISvc = GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2");
  var colItems = objWMISvc.ExecQuery( "Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem");
  for (var it = new Enumerator(colItems); !it.atEnd(); it.moveNext()) {
    var objItem = it.item();
    if (objItem.PartOfDomain)
      continue;
    var strWorkgroup = objItem.Domain;
    var strComputer  = objItem.Name;
    var strPath = "WinNT://" + strWorkgroup + "/" + strComputer + "/" +
      strUsername + ",user";
    try {
      var objIADS = GetObject("WinNT:").OpenDSObject(strPath, strUsername,
        strPassword, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION);

      WScript.Echo("OK");
    } catch(e) {
      WScript.Echo("Invalid Username/Password");
    }
  }
}

ValidateCredentials(WScript.Arguments(0), WScript.Arguments(1));
```

It works fine when I run it from the command prompt, both as an administrator as well as an ordinary user. When the script is invoked by a service process running as the *LocalSystem* user, it doesn't work. Instead the call to OpenDSObject then raises an exception with an error-code of -2147023584 (*A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated*).

What's the problem here, I thought the LocalSystem account is actually more privileged or trusted than administrator accounts?

You can try out the script for yourself by saving it to some .js file and then run it from a command prompt like this:

> cscript.exe validate.js myUsername myPassword

Comment: The LocalSystem account isn't really more or less privileged/trusted than administrator accounts. It's just...differently trusted. That is to say, it has some rights no normal user account has--but it also has some limitations that almost no other account has either.

Comment: This isn't a security issue in any case, i.e., Windows isn't intentionally stopping you from doing this for security reasons.  It's just that whatever exactly OpenDSObject is doing isn't supported in this context.  (It might work from a service configured to run in an actual account.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes it does work if I configure the service to run as administrator but I'm reluctant to do that because every service in the system is configured to run as either LocalSystem or NetworkService so I'm not sure if it'd have any security implications...the service in question is OpenVPN by the way.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Do you happen to have any idea which privilege token I should be looking for? I'm comparing the output of "whoami /priv" for LocalSystem and an ordinary account but not sure what to look for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to validate a password, I'd avoid all of the above. There's a somewhat different method that works nicely from an unprivileged account. In fact, you want to *ensure* the account doesn't actually have the right to change the password.

With this method, you call `NetUserChangePassword`, which requires you to specify the user's existing password in order to authenticate before changing it.

When you do this from an account that doesn't have the right to change that user's password, it will obviously fail (so their password doesn't change). What we care about is exactly *how* it fails. If it fails by returning `ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD`, then you know the password was wrong. If it fails by returning `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, the password was correct, and the function failed because the account you're calling it from doesn't have the right to change that user's password.

So, rather than requiring a highly privileged account like LocalSystem or an administrator, this allows you to do the job from an account with essentially no rights at all (by strong preference, not even the right to change its own password).

Comment: Great, thank you! For the record, I have also found [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/180548/) on MSDN which explains how to make use of the LogonUser WinAPI function to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @Jerry, is that behaviour documented?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes and no. The fact that it can/will return those two values is. I'm not sure if they (currently) have any documentation on the precedence between error values, so if you pass an incorrect password *and* don't have the right to change the password, the return value you'll get is `ERROR_INVALID_PASSWORD`.